# disable break at first line php scripts intellij when debugging?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, xdebug

Intellij suspends my scripts always on the first line of my php scripts when using xdebug, and I don't know why

any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably you've solved this a long time ago, but for the record:

Uncheck Run > Break at first line in PHP Scripts (last menu option in my IDE).

Found it via Ctrl + Shift + A typing "break"

PD. Also almost went nuts while finding it...

Comment: This was driving me nuts too!  This works!  And now I know about the Ctrl + Shift + A command - very convenient.  Thanks!  But WHERE IS THIS IN THE SETTINGS, JetBrains???!  :)

Comment: I would also like to know where it is in normal settings

Comment: Since it is a menu option that can be toggled, why should there be a config option?

Answer (score 3):

Just if you want to localize it in the settings:

Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug:

External connections -> Break at first line in PHP scripts

It is the same place as the screen capture of the question, maybe they updated the view in latests versions of the IDE...

Answer (score 1):

To turn it off or on quickly:

1. Double press Shift to open the quick access menu.
2. type "break at first line"
3. You will be able to switch it off or on from that same window.